# how can i use the Turkish Characters in XML parser?

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, parsing, xml-parsing

i am new on ios programming and i am trying to parse a XML string`:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><SurveyListGetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><SurveyListGetResult>{"SurveyList":[{"SurveyID":1,"SurveyName":"SomeSurvey","SurveyDescription":"Clean","BeginDate":"01.01.2013","EndDate":"05.01.2013"}],"Questions":[{"SurveyID":1,"QuestionID":8,"Question":"Mobile Question","AnswerTypeID":2}],"Answers":[{"SurveyID":1,"QuestionID":8,"AnswerID":18,"Answer":"YES"},{"SurveyID":1,"QuestionID":8,"AnswerID":19,"Answer":"Hayör"}]}</SurveyListGetResult></SurveyListGetResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

this is my xml string and as you see above there is the Turkish character in the "Answer":"Hayör", and i checked the all string, parser is going to until "Hay" but it doesnt take the "ör".

```
 NSData *xmlData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];

    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    [xmlParser parse];
```

this is my parser code and i used to NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding and NSUTF8StringEncoding.
aftes string is going to parser, it is changing like that `{"SurveyList":[{"SurveyID":1,"SurveyName":"Some Survey","SurveyDescription":"Clean","BeginDate":"01.01.2013","EndDate":"05.01.2013"}],"Questions":[{"SurveyID":1,"QuestionID":8,"Question":"Mobil Soru","AnswerTypeID":2}],"Answers":[{"SurveyID":1,"QuestionID":8,"AnswerID":18,"Answer":"YES"},{"SurveyID":1,"QuestionID":8,"AnswerID":19,"Answer":"Hay`

what i need to do for solve it? Sorry for my bad english,Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding what do you get if you use NSUTF8StringEncoding?

Comment: i tried NSUTF8StringEncoding but i am taking same error.

Comment: How are you reading and showing the string that you show the result?

Comment: this string is coming from webservice and im using the standard xml parser way -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    
    //NSLog(@"Element started %@",elementName);
    self.currentElement=elementName;
    
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    
    //NSLog(@"Element ended %@",elementName);
    self.currentElement=@"";
    
}

Comment: How did you get the string to cut and paste here?

Answer (score 0):

I would try passing the data **to** the parser as NSUTF8StringEncoding and after that convert it to whatever encoding you want to use for Turkish. If this doesn't work, I'd try string escaping using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`

Also... Have you noticed that the data within the **SurveyListGetResult** tag is actually a JSON string?